# How to implement different class types within one variable?

Tags: c#

I have 3 object classes:

```
public class MessageData
{
    public string MessageID { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public bool IsSent { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeInfo { get; set; }
}

public class MultiMessageData
{
    public string MessageID { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public bool IsSent { get; set; }
    public byte MessageType { get; set; }
    public string MessageType { get; set; }
    public string Platform { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeInfo { get; set; }
}

public class SocialData
{
    public string MessageID { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public bool IsSent { get; set; }
    public bool IsReceived { get; set; }
    public byte MessageType { get; set; }
    public string MessageType { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have a function right now that only implement the MessageData class:

```
public void SendData()
{
    List<MessageData> data = new List<MessageData>();

    // some work here with data variable...

    _sendRepository.Send(data);
}
```

Now what I need is to keep most of the logic but a way that I can instantiate a variable that can be of any class type for example:

```
public void SendData()
{
    var data;

    if(logic == 1){
        data = new List<MessageData>();
    } else if(logic == 2){
        data = new List<MultiMessageData>();
    }else {
        data = new List<SocialData>();
    }

    // some work here...

    // if I do that then this Send method I will change it to be a Generic T maybe.
    _sendRepository.Send(data);
}
```

Any clue?

Comment: inheritance I presume?

Comment: Do you can use generic method for it? I mean that you can swap definition of `SendData` to `SendData<T>` and invoke closed type by your `logic`

Comment: Use interfaces.

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria The repository Send method will have a generic method but the SendData method cant be Generic

Comment: Either interfaces or abstract classes would be a good direction to go here.

Comment: you cant have properties on interfaces

Comment: @Alander yes you can.

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance is the way to go:

```
public class MessageDataBase
{
    public string MessageID { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public bool IsSent { get; set; }
}
public class MessageData : MessageDataBase
{
    public string EmployeeInfo { get; set; }
}

public class MultiMessageData : MessageDataBase
{
    public byte MessageType { get; set; }
    public string MessageTypeString { get; set; }
    public string Platform { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeInfo { get; set; }
}

public class SocialData : MessageDataBase
{
    public bool IsReceived { get; set; }
    public byte MessageType { get; set; }
    public string MessageTypeString { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: But then in the funciton method how can I do my logic?

Comment: You would have the Send method take a parameter of MessageDataBase that way it can just take any Message that inherits from MessageDataBase.

Answer (score 1):

Use an interface, but you will have to make common changes in the `//..do some work here section`

```
public interface IMessageData
{
    //Example required function for all MessageData classes
    void SetDate(DateTime date);
    void SetIsSent(bool date);
}
public abstract class BaseMessageData : IMessageData
{
    public string MessageID { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public bool IsSent { get; set; }

    public BaseMessageData(string messageID)
    {
        MessageID=messageID;
    }
    public void SetDate(DateTime date)
    {
        Date = date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
    }
    public void SetIsSent(bool sentStatus)
    {
        IsSent = sentStatus;
    }
}
public class MessageData : BaseMessageData, IMessageData
{

    public string EmployeeInfo { get; set; }

}

public class MultiMessageData : MessageData,IMessageData
{
    public byte MessageType { get; set; }
    public string MessageType { get; set; }

    public string Platform { get; set; }
}

public class SocialData : BaseMessageData, IMessageData
{
    public bool IsReceived { get; set; }

    public byte MessageType { get; set; }
    //Can't have to properties named the same. 
    //public string MessageType { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your `SendData`

```
public void SendData()
{
    List<IMessageData> data;

    if (logic == 1)
    {
        data = new List<MessageData>();
    }
    else if (logic == 2)
    {
        data = new List<MultiMessageData>();
    }
    else
    {
        data = new List<SocialData>();
    }

    // some work here...
    foreach (var d in data)
    {
        //Only methods that will work are ones declared in the IMessageData interface
        d.SesDate(DateTime.Now);
        d.SetIsSent(true);
    }

    // if I do that then this Send method I will change it to be a Generic T maybe.
    _sendRepository.Send(data);
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution. Interfaces should be used in these kind of scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my open source library, OneOf https://github.com/mcintyre321/OneOf

A OneOf is a special Type which can hold one value from a range of Types, like a Discriminated Union in F#. It provides an alternative to using inheritance/polymorphism.

You would write your method like this:

```
public void SendData()
{
    OneOf<List<MessageData>, List<MultiMessageData>, List<SocialData>> data = null;

    if(logic == 1){
        data = new List<MessageData>();
    } else if(logic == 2){
        data = new List<MultiMessageData>();
    }else {
        data = new List<SocialData>();
    }

    // some work here...


    _sendRepository.Send(data);
}
```

Or you could have `var data = List<OneOf<MessageData, MultiMessageData, SocialData>>();` if you prefer, especially if you want to have different 
Types in the list.

> install-package OneOf

It supports net451 and netstandard1.6